# Rewriting URL with "///" at the end

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following problem with my URLs on my website: Both **www.domain.com/example/ and www.domain.com/example////** are showing me the same page. (duplicate content)
The "////" problem occurs for all my pages. To solve this I tried to redirect the `URLs` from  **www.domain.com/example////** to  **www.domain.com/example/** (via .`htaccess`) but it doesn't work.

Could you please tell my what I'm doing wrong?
Here the code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/+ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule in your site root .htaccess to remove multiple slashes

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```